# Is it just me or is this textbook on PHP and MySQL wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MphM.png

The last line. It clear shows customers with NULL orderids... I'm confused.

Comment: Please tell me you screencapped it at that scroll position for a purpose.

Comment: So you could have the code, yeah...

Comment: The text is clearly wrong there. Is that the "Learning PHP & MySQL" book from O'Reilly with the birds on the cover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the last line appears to be in conflict.  Typos are natural.  I'd suggest emailing in the author if it's troubling folks.

Answer (score 0):

Not all customers can have an order (and a corresponding order ID).

(Also, is that last line describing another table below? If not, it is an error in the book.)

A query that would perform that action would need a `WHERE` clause:

`... WHERE orderid IS NOT NULL`

Comment: That's what I was referring to. It refers to the above table, not another one.

Comment: Then it is definitely an error because, clearly, there are `NULL`s in the `orderid` column.

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks, wanted to make sure. Should have been more specific.